# How i fix this error?

Tags: asp.net

I have error in

plz help to convert json to rcpts.

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(rcpts);
```

```css
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace sdd.Contact
{
    public partial class Cantact : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void SabtButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://ippanel.com/services.jspd");
            string[] rcpts = new string[] { "981111111" };
            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(rcpts);
            request.Method = "POST";
            string postData = "op=send&uname=aaaa&pass=0000&message=hello Test&to=" + json + "&from=+9810001010";
            byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
            Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
            dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
            dataStream.Close();
            WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
            Console.WriteLine(((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription);
            dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
            string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
            Console.WriteLine(responseFromServer);
            reader.Close();
            dataStream.Close();
            response.Close();
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(responseFromServer);

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try `Parse` or `DeserializeObject` for this:

```
JObject json = JObject.Parse(rcpts);
```

Or

```
dynamic json  = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(rcpts);
```

Comment: thank you for answer
 but:
 DeserializeObject : The name 'JsonConvert' does not exist in the current context plz help me again

Comment: you need to import `jsonConvert`. For that you need to install `Newtonsoft.Json`."Manage NuGet packages" -> Search for "newtonsoft json". -> click "install".